# Compatible issue with the Wordpress theme for IE and Firefox

Tags: wordpress

Here is the link for our wordpress site http://www.dotmappersdesign.com/caramaintaince/.

We have a compatibility issue with internet explorer and mozilla firefox. We tried few methods to solve, like 
1) Creating a separate css file ie.css.
2) Writing version code in header.php (  )

But the issue is not fixed.

All your answers are appreciated.

Comment: Can you detail what is wrong? I don't see what is wrong with it on Firefox. Without specifics how can we help?

Comment: On this page http://www.dotmappersdesign.com/caramaintaince/insurance-repairs/, text and image are not aligned properly but if you see in chrome it works fine.

Comment: On this page http://www.dotmappersdesign.com/caramaintaince/insurance-repairs/, text and image are not aligned properly but if you see in chrome it works fine. This is the other page http://www.dotmappersdesign.com/caramaintaince/authorized-repairers/ where text is overlapping. kindly give some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please changes the css line in logo class width 150px issue solved in mozilla firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

On the insurance-repairs page that is happening because of the `span8` class, remove it from the `<div class="span8 right" id="content" data-motopress-type="loop" data-motopress-loop-file="loop/loop-page.php">` div and it should display fine.

The issue on the authorized-repairs page is happening because of `right: 250px;` on the `<ul>` that, remove it and it should fix it.